# how to retrieve unsigned integer from NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, unsigned

I have saved an u_int32_t value in NSUserDefaults using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:(unsigned value) forKey:@"xyz"]
```

But i am not able to retrieve it using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"xyz"]
```

Comment: What do you get back from the `objectForKey:` call?

Comment: Warning: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'u_int32_t from 'id_Nullable'

Comment: i want to store it in 'u_int32_t' variable.

Answer (score 4):

> I get "Warning: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'u_int32_t from 'id_Nullable'"

This is because you get back your `unsigned int` wrapped in an `NSNumber`. Now you need to unwrap it:

```
unsigned int uv = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"xyz"] unsignedIntValue];
```

Comment: You are great man.Upvote  for your good answer.I tried give solution but there is no way than your answer.it gives what exactly OP wants.